# How do I use a different template for the anonymous users?

Tags: 7, theming

If the user is the anonymous user or an authenticated user, I want to use the page1.tpl.php; with other roles, I want to use page.tpl.php.
How do I write the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not need an additional page1.tpl.php. In the page.tpl.php you can use:

```
<?php
  global $user;

  if ($user->uid > 0) {
    print /* Insert content only for authenticated users. */;
  }
?>
```

If you want to show some content when the user has the "administrator" role, then you can use:

```
<?php
  global $user;

  if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles)))) {
    print /* Insert content only for users with "administrator" role. */;
  }
?>
```

Comment: if i want to print other things when the user role is admin, how to get that?

Comment: I updated the answer with the content of the comment.

Comment: Actually, a cleaner way to figure out if the user is anonymous is to call the function user_is_anonymous()

Comment: [user_is_anonymous()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_is_anonymous/6) returns TRUE also when the user is not the anonymous user, but the variable `$GLOBALS['menu_admin']` is not empty (e.g. it is not `FALSE`).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to handle different templates for different scenarios the [context module](http://drupal.org/project/context) is a great tool. This case is quite simple, so you could handle it with code like suggested. But using the context module, makes it a bit more manageable, and allows you not only to decide what template to use, to also what blocks to insert. It's a great module and is one of those I use for almost all of the sites I make.

Comment: many thanks, i will make a try to the module that you suggested.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use Context. I would rather avoid to alter a theme template, when it is not necessary. Altering theme templates of a third-party theme would mean to override the theme templates used by the theme all times the theme is updated; it would also mean to alter the theme templates of every theme users could select for themselves.

Comment: i want to know What's the  main use of the  context module?

Comment: The Context **Layout** module would offer you this ability. It's main purpose is to setup **conditions** and **reactions** one of which is to use a different page.tpl.php with a different set of regions setup in your .info file.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use a preprocess function. Something like that:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_page($vars) {
   global $user;
   if (!$user->uid || in_array('user authenticated', array_values($user->roles))) {
      $vars['template_files'][] = 'page1';
   }
}
```

Comment: what's this '(!$user->uid |' meaning? thank you

Comment: It is not necessary to verify if the user as the "user authenticated" role. The user ID for anonymous users is 0, and authenticated users have an user ID that is greater than 0; the user with ID equal to 1 is the user who has all the permissions.

Comment: i don't know "if (!$user->uid | "  meaning.could you explain it. thank you.

Comment: @enjoylife It's a typo; it should be `if (!$user->uid || in_array('user authenticated', array_values($user->roles)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Every user on a Drupal site is an anonymous user, or an authenticated user. Requiring to use the page1.tpl.php template for anonymous, or authenticated users would mean that the page1.tpl.php template is always used.

if by authenticated users you mean users that don't have any other specific role, then you could use the following code in your page.tpl.php file.

```
if (empty(array_diff(array_keys($GLOBALS['user']->roles), array(0, 1))) {
  // The user is anonymous, or the user doesn't have other roles
  // apart the one of authenticated user.
}
```